# flaw in finding next map in cofiber sequence

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fibration

I have used the cofiber sequence many times.  I decided to try and derive it myself since I had managed to forget it.

Let $A \hookrightarrow X$ be a cofibration.  Consider the projection $X \to X/A$.  The 'next term' in the cofibration sequence is the cofiber of this map when I turn $X \xrightarrow{q} X/A$ into a cofibration.  The standard way of doing this is substituting for the inclusion of $X  \hookrightarrow M_q$.  The cofiber of this map is  $M_q/X:=\frac{(X \times I)/((x,1) \sim (\overline{x},1))}{X \times 0}=Cone(X/A)$.

This is not the standard correct answer I get by substituting the map $X \to X/A$ by $X \to Cone(A \hookrightarrow X)$(the cofiber of this map is the suspension of $A$).

What is the flaw in my first argument?

Comment: What you want is $A\to X\to \operatorname{cone}(A\to X)\to \Sigma X\to \Sigma Y\to\cdots$ right?

Comment: Right.  So baisically I know how to get the right answer $A \to X \to cone(A \to X) \to \Sigma A \to Sigma X...$.  Because I know that this is the right answer and that the answer I got was not this, I know that the answer I got was wrong, and I want to know what the flaw is in my proof of my provisional answer.

Comment: Thanks so much for answering all of my questions so far.  Your willingness to help in the questions heavy in notation, such as the spectral sequence questions, has been a godsend.

Comment: I understand this.  I understand that that one can use the homotopy equivalence $X/A \to Cone(A \to X)$ turns $X \to X/A$ into a cofibration.  But what happens if you used the homotopy equivalence $X/A \to Mappingcylinder(X \to X/A)$ to turn $X \to X/A$ into a cofibration?

Comment: The problem that seems to be happening above is that when I turn $X \to X/A$ into a cofibration, in this way, the cofiber of this map is $M_{X \to X/A}/(X \times \{0\})=C(X/A)$.  This is certainly not homotopy equivalent to $\Sigma A$.

Comment: Let $i:A\hookrightarrow X$. I think the flaw in your first argument is that you consider the projection $X\to X/A$ instead of the inclusion $X\to \operatorname{cone}(i)$. While it is true that $\operatorname{cone}(i)\simeq X/A$, it makes a difference for the next term in the sequence, which is the cone of the preceding map. When we identify the next term with $\Sigma A$, we used that the map $X\to \operatorname{cone}(i)$ is a cofibration.

Comment: $X \to Mappingcylinder(X \to X/A)$ is also a cofibration, with $Mappingcylinder(X \to X/A) \cong cone(i) \cong X/A$.

Comment: Right, fair enough, now I see what you were trying to do. Btw., those are only homotopy equivalences, right?

Comment: yuuuuuuuuuuuppp.(sorry I had to get to 8 characters :))

Comment: Another comment: Why did we start with a cofibration $A\hookrightarrow X$? We have a cofiber sequence for any map $A\to X$. The way I view it is we turn $A\to X$ into a cofibration using the mapping cone construction. Then we iterate, forming the mapping cone of $X\to \operatorname{cone}(A\to X)$, and so on. If we had used the mapping cylinder construction this would be boring because all spaces would be homotopy equivalent to $X$.

Comment: You seem to have a different view of how the cofiber sequence arises, which is interesting.

Comment: One can't turn an arbitrary map $A \xrightarrow{i} X$ into a cofibration via a mapping cone constructon, unless the $M_i/A$ has the homotopy type of the suspension of some space.  If $M_i/A \cong \Sigma Y$ for some $Y$ then the homotopy cofiber of $A \to X$ is $ cone(Y \to A)$

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right :) I was talking nonsense above, sorry.